# LineRenderer How to delete any point?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to delete the starting points of the Linderenderer. Is there a way to delete points as in a list `list.RemoveAt(1);`. Or turn it over somehow to reduce the number of points, starting from the initial

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of points, then add it to your LineRender like that :
`lineRenderer.SetPositions(points);`

You can remove values in your array something like that :

```
var pointsList = new List<Vector3>(pointsArray);
pointsList.RemoveAt(1);
pointsArray = pointsList.ToArray();
```

Then update your lineRenderer with the new array of points.

Comment: `Vector3[] pointsArray = new Vector3[]
        {
            new Vector3(1, 0, 0),
            new Vector3(0, 1, 0),
            new Vector3(0, 0, 1)
        };` or create a List of points and convert it to array. It depends of your needs !

Comment: Sorry but it's not work . Not deleted, points do not disappear

Comment: I tried a sample code which was working. You need to update the number of positions with something like that : `lineRenderer.positionCount = pointsArray.Length;`